# Como fazer o JTextField se comportar como ComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Gostaria de saber se há como transformar meu JTextField em uma espécie de combo box.

Gostaria que quando eu digitasse algo, esse dado fosse se relacionando automaticamente com algum banco de dados e fosse aparecendo opções de escolha para mim, como acontece na barra de endereço de um navegador por exemplo.

Gostaria apenas de um exemplo a partir de um JTextField simples de como posso fazer para que essa lista de opções apareça.

Código simples:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class NewClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja a resposta do diegoaugusto, é exatamente o que voce precisa

Comment: Exatamente o que eu queria, muito obrigado! @Articuno